# ProgressDialog not showing while thread is running

Tags: android, multithreading, progressdialog

I am trying to display a ProgressDialog while I am loading some data from an API. I put the APIPost into a thread, and for debugging purposes, I have been putting the thread to sleep for 3 seconds trying to get the dialog to appear. However, when I start the thread, no dialog appears and the UI thread just hangs. Am I missing something?

```
final ProgressDialog dialog;

    dialog = new ProgressDialog(MyClassName.this);

    dialog.setTitle("");
    dialog.setMessage("Loading...");
    dialog.setCancelable(false);

    Thread runner = new Thread(){
        JSONObject jTemp;
        @Override
        public void run(){
            try {
                synchronized(this){
                    wait(3000);
                }
                getFarmProperties.postAPI(tempAddress);

                do {
                    jTemp = getFarmProperties.getJSON();
                } while (jTemp == null);
            }
            catch(InterruptedException ex){
            }

        }
    };

    try {
        runner.start();
        dialog.show();
        runner.join();
        dialog.dismiss();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: Is there a reason you're not using an AsyncTask instead?

Comment: I am using an AsyncTask in my postAPI method. I've tried putting this in an AsyncTask as well with the same results

Comment: Where do you call this from? `runner.join()` causes the current thread to wait for the background thread to terminate. If you call this on the UI thread, you effectively stop your UI from updating until the background thread is finished.

Comment: I am calling this within my `onCreate()`. This makes a lot more sense why the dialog is not showing up

Answer (score 0):

runner.join blocks the UI thread until runner eventually completes. As suggested use AsyncTask instead.

Answer (score 0):

```
runner.start();
dialog.show();
runner.join();
dialog.dismiss();
```

This essentially starts the thread, posts a request to show the progress dialog, waits for the thread to finish and then dismisses the progress dialog.

Since the progress dialog is only drawn when the UI thread has a chance to process the message queue, it gets never drawn in the first place.

Either use [`AsyncTask`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) and dismiss the dialog in [`onPostExecute()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#onPostExecute%28Result%29) or get rid of the `join()` and dismiss the progress dialog when the background thread has finished using [`runOnUIThread()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#runOnUiThread%28java.lang.Runnable%29). I suggest using `AsyncTask` because it does all the management for you including convenient callback methods.